# Highlight and unhighlight images - click problems

Tags: javascript

I have got this working as a multi-select that highlights each image on the first click, then unhighlights on the second click. However, sometimes the image will need to be clicked on twice to change, and sometimes only once. I can't figure out why!

Here is my code:

```
var ImageSelector = function() {
              var imgs = null;
              //var selImg = null;
              var clicked = false;
              var unClicked = true;

              return {
                 addImages: function(container) {
                    imgs = container.getElementsByTagName("img");


                    for(var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; i++) {
                       var img = imgs[i];

                        // img.className = "normal";


                       img.onclick = function()  {


                          if(unClicked == true)   {
                             this.className = "highlighted";
                             clicked = true;
                             unClicked = false;
                          }

                          else  if(clicked == true)   {
                             this.className = "normal";
                             clicked = false;
                             unClicked = true;
                          }



                       };
                    }
                 }
              };
           }();


var div = document.getElementById("Images");
              ImageSelector.addImages(div);
```

Comment: maybe because of the use of the id, id have to be unique you have to get images by className

Comment: First of all: the independant use of "clicked" and "unclicked" seems redundant - why not just toggle "clicked" and check if it is true or false?
Second: IDs should ALWAYS be unique, as @Amani pointed out.
Third: Can you give us your HTML setup, or a working representation? It's quite tedious to just go through every little line and "imagine" it running.
Fourth: You could also iterate through the result of your getElementsByTagName directly, since you're not using your `i` variable.
...and to make things simpler: is jQuery a viable option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clicked/unClicked variables are unnecessary here, because what you are essentially doing is toggling a class on each image.

Your code can be massively reduced to:

```js
var ImageSelector = function() {    
    return {
        addImages: function(container) {         
            container.onclick = function(e)  { 
                var target = e.target;                
                if(target.nodeName === "IMG") {
                    target.className = (target.className === "highlighted") ? "normal" : "highlighted";   
                }
            };            
        }
    };
}();

var div = document.getElementById("Images");
ImageSelector.addImages(div);
```

```css
img {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px black solid;
}

.highlighted {
    background-color: red;
}

.normal {
   
}
```

```html
<div id="Images">
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
```

Also, as a side note, if you know your variable is a Boolean before checking it in a conditional statement, you should use === or simply `if(myVar)` or `if(!myVar)` for checking truthy and falsy conditions, respectively.

I hope this helps.